# $l^2(A)$ is unitarily isomorphic to $l^2(B)$ implies $card(A)=card(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$l^2(A)$ is unitarily isomorphic to $l^2(B)$ implies $card(A)=card(B)$

How can we construct the map from A to B via the unitary map?

Unitary map is a invertible map between Hilbert spaces that preserves inner product.

The question comes from Folland's real analysis P178 ex 65

Comment: Hint: to show that they are of the same cardinality, you have to (by definition) find a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ that would be one-to-one and onto. And you know that they are isomorphic, i.e. that exists a unitary map from one to the other.

Comment: The unitary map is the map from $l^2(A)$ to $l^2(B)$, how can we construct a map from A to B via this map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: What's the (Hilbert) dimension of $\ell^2(A)$? Or if you don't know what Hilbert dimension is, find a maximal orthogonal set in $\ell^2(A)$ and show that the cardinality of such a set is unique (using the same method as for proving that the cardinality of a basis of a vector space is unique).

Comment: ???it's not me.